# Symfony Finder - "The "1" directory does not existf

Tags: php, symfony, finder

so I have a file (just a basic text file) that I want to read in to my `Controller` so I can display the output on a twig page.
My code (in my controller) is as follows:

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Finder;
```

...

```
$finder = new Finder();
$finder->files()->in($finder->in(__DIR__.'/../BusinessLogic'));

  foreach ($finder as $file) {
    $contents = $file->getContents();
  }
//return etc
```

given that the controller is in `src/Controller` and the file I want to access is in `src/BusinessLogic` this should work, but it comes up with an error page saying `the "1" directory does not exist` (InvalidArgumentException). As far as I can see it should be valid.

PS does anyone know how to access a specific file, rather than just searching a folder? docs weren't very clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$finder->in(...)` return `$this`.

So replace

`$finder->files()->in($finder->in(__DIR__.'/../BusinessLogic'));`

by

`$finder->files()->in(__DIR__.'/../BusinessLogic');`